# laravel 5.2 auth login and csrf not working

Tags: laravel, session, authentication

I got a big problem here my app run smoothly until one day my AUTH building is not working anymore. It keep telling token mismatch error but when I try to disable CSRF, the login always redirects me back to login page like AUTH false. Can someone help me what am I missing here? I'm using Laravel 5.2

**route code:**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {

    Route::get('/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
    Route::post('/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
    Route::get('/home', 'AdminController@index');
});
```

**kernal.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;
class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    ];
    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,

        ],
        'auth' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        ],
        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
        ],
    ];
    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    ];
}
```

**admincontroller**

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Booking;
use App\Booktour;
use App\Bookcustomer;
use App\Bookdiscount;
use App\Booktourpay;
use App\Customerorder;
use App\Tourdetail;
use App\Tourperiod;
use App\Tourlead;
use Session;
use View;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Auth;
use Datetime;
use DB;
use Image;
use App\User;

class AdminController extends Controller {

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Home Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller renders your application's "dashboard" for users that
    | are authenticated. Of course, you are free to change or remove the
    | controller as you wish. It is just here to get your app started!
    |
    */

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $count_customer = Bookcustomer::count();    
        $getuser = Auth::user()->name;
        $booking_order = Booking::where('sales_name', '=',$getuser)
                                        ->orderby('created_at', 'DSEC')
                                        ->get();    
        $booktour_open = DB::table('tourlist')->where('status' ,'=', 'เปิดขาย')->count();
        $tour = Booktour::where('status', 'เปิดขาย')
                                ->orderby('depart_date', 'asc')
                                ->get();
        $unpaid = Booking::where('sales_name', '=', $getuser)
                                ->where('status', 'รอเงินโอน')
                                ->count();      

        $allbook_list = Booking::where('status', '=', "รอเงินโอน")->orderby('created_at', 'DSEC')->get();   
        $today_date = strtotime('now');     
        $payment_list = Booktourpay::Today()->get();

        $user_list_payment = Booktourpay::where('create_by', '=', $getuser)->get();

        return view('admin.home')
        ->with('booking_order', $booking_order)
        ->with('count_customer', $count_customer)
        ->with('booktour_open', $booktour_open)
        ->with('tour', $tour)
        ->with('unpaid', $unpaid)
        ->with('allbook_list', $allbook_list)
        ->with('payment_list', $payment_list)
        ->with('user_list_payment', $user_list_payment);
    }
```

**authcontroller**

```
       <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */

    protected $loginPath = '/login';  

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

I get weird redirect after login whether user/password is correct or not.